# Procedure to migrate from IBM MQ to ActiveMQ

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, middleware, mq

I just need to know some basic information or the procedure that is followed when migrating from IBM MQ server to ActiveMQ. We are planning to migrate our messaging systems from IBM MQ to Active MQ.

To be specific the migration is from MQ V7.0 to ActiveMQ V5.7.0. What would be the object movement from  IBM MQ to ActiveMQ i.e., to know the comparison or the relation between MQ objects and ActiveMQ if there are any.( IBM MQ queue->? in ActiveMQ and other major things)

It would be greatly appreciable if someone would provide me some insight on this. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.7 is very old, use the new ActiveMQ 5.13.x release.

Answer (score 3):

It's a large topic depending on the complexity of your setup.

Here are some high level topics to consider.

**Clients**

***JMS***

If you are using IBM WebSphere MQ with JMS clients those clients will need to replace their IBM libraries with ActiveMQ ones and replace the configuration.

***MQ Native***

Using native MQ clients will require you to rewrite your applications to use any of the client libraries available for ActiveMQ. This might be non straight forward.

**QMGR Configuration**

***Queues and topics***

Simple objects in WMQ such Queues and Topics are the same in ActiveMQ, although you do not have to explicitly define them.

***Cluster Configuration***

WMQ clusters are roughly the same as AMQ Network of Brokers. However, in AMQ message propagation is pretty much automatic and all queues are global (by default). Most features should be possible to migrate, one way or another.

***HA Configuration***

AMQ uses similar fail-over setups as WMQ, where a shared network disk is the most common.

***Security***

AMQ and WMQ have different security mechanisms but support users, passwords, authorities, security groups, TLS transport security etc etc. A migration path should be possible but may not be straight forward in some scenarios.